# RegisterStartupScript in a loop

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have a problem with call javascript function(in .aspx file) from C#(in .aspx.cs file) in loop. The code below doesn't work. Nothing happens. What's wrong? I read a few posts on stack overflow about it, but nothing work.

Here is code:

```
int i = 1;
while (i<10)
{
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "key" + i.ToString(), "myFunction('" + i + "')", true);
    i++;
}
```

JavaScript function

```
function myFunction(i){
    document.write(i);
}
```

But this code work, but it doesn't interest me.

```
string something = "something";
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "key", "myFunction('" + something + "')", true);
```

Comment: Integers are automatically parsed into a string value when necessary in Javascript, C#, and VB.NET; `i.ToString()` is unnecessary. Other than that, you need to add `;` to the end of your function, other wise you will get something like this rendered on your page: `myFunction('1')myFunction('2')myFunction('3')myFunction('4')`

Comment: Your code actually works in my environment though. Although I did convert it to VB.NET.

Comment: of course i forgot `;` on the end of my function. thanks for the answers Steve Padmore and Lopsided

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of your loop, try this:

```
        ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;
        string csName = "MyScript";
        Type csType = this.GetType();

        for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            string currentName = string.Format("{0}{1}", csName, i);
            if (!cs.IsStartupScriptRegistered(csType, currentName))
            {
                string csText = string.Format("myFunction('{0}');", i);
                cs.RegisterStartupScript(csType, currentName, csText, true);
            }
        }
```

Comment: I also encourage you to use the String.Format function. Example: `String.Format("myFunction('{0}');",i)`